# What does this quote stand for?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Can somebody explain me please what does [this quote by Countess Morphy](https://books.google.com/books?id=bcKGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA484&dq=%22plain+cooking+cannot+be+entrusted+to+plain+cooks&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic1ffDz5fsAhURr54KHfGeCccQ6AEwA3oECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Plain%20cooking%20cannot%20be%20entrusted%20to%20plain%20cooks%22&f=false) mean?

> Plain cooking cannot be entrusted to plain cooks.

Comment: I don't recognise this as a standard English proverb. Where did you come across it?

Comment: Even routine, everyday cooking needs a degree of expertise [to be acceptable]. But as BoldBen essentially is saying, unless dictums are well used, requests for meaning are off-topic on ELU as general comprehension exercises.

Comment: @BoldBen this quote is Countess Morphy's.

Comment: @javaistaucheineinsel In that case it's not really a dictum, it's a clever remark by a food critic. She's probably right in that plain cooking takes skill and flair to make it work well but it's neither an authoritative statement nor a set phrase (at least not yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me serve up an analogy.  It takes a talented and experienced actor to best play the role of an idiot.  Of course, it takes a degree of ability to cook, too, but, I think that it's the paradoxical element here. That, when it comes right down to it, very few of us can appear normal, "mad", or whatever.

QUOTATIONS

If cooking becomes an art form rather than a means of providing a reasonable diet, then something is clearly wrong
[Tom Jaine, Editor of The Good Food Guide]

Cooking is like love. It should be entered into with abandon or not at all
[Harriet Van Horne]

Life is too short to stuff a mushroom
[Shirley Conran – Superwoman]

The tragedy of English cooking is that ‘plain’ cooking cannot be entrusted to ‘plain’ cooks
[Countess Morphy – English Recipes]